# Как запустить скрипт .py через другой скрипт в новом окне на mac os?

Tags: python

Мне нужно открыть новый скрипт, при этом не приостанавливая первый скрипт
(os.system мне не подходит). Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Зачем запускать еще один интерпретатор? Почему не подходит вариант с импортом?

Answer (score 0):

Код ниже должен запустить скрипт, путь или название которого вы запишите в переменную `script_path`.

```
import subprocess

script_path = 'script.py'
subprocess.call(['python', script_path], shell=True)
```

Обратите внимание, что метод `call` библиотеки `subprocess` может принимать на вход как список, так и строку. К примеру, параметр `['python', script_path]` может быть успешно заменен строкой `'python' + script_path`.

P.S. Если не заработает - пишите, я догадываюсь, в чем еще может возникнуть проблема.